# Stopping asyncio in thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a thread that start (and eventually stops) a asyncio loop like so:

```
class Ook(Thread):

    […]

    def run(self):
        try:
            self._logger.debug("Asyncio loop runs forever.")
            self.loop.run_forever()
        except Exception as ex:
            # We do want to see ALL unhandled exceptions here.
            self._logger.error("Exception raised: %s", ex)
            self._logger.exception(ex)
        finally:
            # Stop the loop!
            self._logger.warn('Closing asyncio event loop.')
            self.loop.run_until_complete(self.loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
            self.loop.close()

    def stop(self):
        self._logger.info("Thread has been asked to stop!")
        if self.loop.is_running():
            self._logger.debug("Asked running asyncio loop to stop.")
            for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
                self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(task.cancel)
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)
```

A silly (?) unit test to check that works is

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_start_and_stop_thread():
    sut = Ook()
    sut.start()
    if sut.isAlive():
        sut.stop()
        sut.join()
    assert not sut.isAlive()
    assert not sut.loop.is_running()
```

This does not work because of raised `asyncio.CancelledError`… Catching those anywhere in the `stop` method does not seem to help.

If I run the test code not marked with `@pytest.mark.asyncio`, I get a message saying `Task was destroyed but it is pending!`.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Try to wait a few seconds before check `isAlive`?

Comment: @Sraw Why would that help? In any case, I tried it and it does not.

Comment: Because I think it may caused by calling `stop` before `run` completes. Unfortunately it seems not.

Comment: @Sraw That was a fair point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have several issues here.

1. the Task.cancel() raises a asyncio.CancelledError() inside the couroutine. You should add a "try/exec CancelledError" in your coroutines to handle that exception.
2. Another way could be suppressing the CancelledError exception in the def stop:

   ```
   from asyncio import CancelledError
   from contextlib import suppress

   def stop(self):
       self._logger.info("Thread has been asked to stop!")
       if self.loop.is_running():
           self._logger.debug("Asked running asyncio loop to stop.")
           self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)
           for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
               task.cancel()
               with suppress(CancelledError):
                   loop.run_until_complete(task)
   ```
3. remember to close also all asynchronous generators with

   ```
   loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
   ```

Comment: Looks like it should be `for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks(self.loop):`. Without the param the array returned is empty.

Comment: Now `asyncio.all_tasks(loop=self.loop)`